# SychronizationContext.Post usage

Tags: c#, .net, concurrency

I have a producer/consumer pattern, where I need to inform the producer when the item has been consumed sucessfully. Basically a producer gives me an `TransportTask` an `Action<TransportTask>` to call when its ready. What I want to do is post it in the same SyncContext where it came from.

```
public class TaskProcessAgent : ITaskProcessAgent
{
    private Dictionary<TransportTask, Tuple<Action<TransportTask>, SynchronizationContext>> m_tasks = new Dictionary<TransportTask, Tuple<Action<TransportTask>, SynchronizationContext>>();
    private BlockingCollection<TransportTask> m_taskQueue = new BlockingCollection<TransportTask>();
    private TaskCoordinator m_coordinator;

    public TaskProcessAgent(TaskCoordinator coordinator)
    {
        m_coordinator = coordinator;
        m_coordinator.OnTaskReady += OnTaskReady;

        Task.Factory.StartNew(() =>
            {
                foreach (var _task in m_taskQueue.GetConsumingEnumerable())
                    ProcessTask(_task);
            },
            TaskCreationOptions.LongRunning);
    }

    public void Process(TransportTask task, Action<TransportTask> onReady)
    {
        lock (m_tasks)
        {
            m_tasks.Add(task, Tuple.Create(onReady, SynchronizationContext.Current ?? new SynchronizationContext()));
        }
        m_taskQueue.Add(task);
    }

    public void SetCompleted(TransportTask task)
    {
        m_coordinator.SetCompleted(task);
    }

    private void OnTaskReady(TransportTask task)
    {
        m_tasks[task].Item2.Post(p => m_tasks[task].Item1(task), null);
    }

    private void ProcessTask(TransportTask transportTask)
    {
        m_coordinator.AddTask(transportTask);
    }
}
```

Here `OnTaskReady` will be called by `TaskCoordinator` from it's own thread. What I want is to call the callback from the same SychronizationContext which called `Process`.

I'm not sure it's going to work and I need to write a lot more code to get to a point where I can test whether it works. The crucial line is `m_tasks[task].Item2.Post(p => m_tasks[task].Item1(task), null);` and I'm not sure it works this way.

Comment: To solve what problem you're trying to post it to `SynchronizationContext` ?

Comment: Question edited. I want to call the callback in the same context as Process was called.

Comment: I can't understand. No offense. Are you sure that you understand about `SynchronizationContext`? It is not necessarily meant or belong to single thread. `new SynchronizationContext()` would post the call to `ThreadPool`.

Comment: Looks like you are trying to replicate what Tasks already do, by using a callback instead of a continuation (ContinueWith). The typical agent/actor implementation is to return a Task from Process that completes when processing of the message completes. The caller can then continue on its preferred SynchronizationContext

Comment: @SriramSakthivel: Sometimes "Process" may be called from the UI, with callback updating it, this is why I need that here.

Comment: @Panagiotis: I'm not creating a new TPL Task for each if my tasks, they are all (going to be processed in fewer threads (atm 1))

Comment: just add a lock when you access the `m_tasks` store it in a local, then post it. that should work.

Comment: @Lev Tasks do not correspond to Threads. You can use a TaskCompletionSource to return a Task without calling Task.Run. BTW, why aren't you using TPL DataFlow and an ActionBlock?